# Como fazer um lightbox com CSS e jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou querendo fazer uma barra de *login* com *lightbox*, ou seja, quando clicar no *link* "entrar no *site*" vai aparecer uma `<div>` que estava oculta e aparecerá um fundo escuro transparente.

Como se constrói algo assim?

Comment: Estou reabrindo porque os princípios para se fazer isso são bem simples, e podem tranquilamente ser explicados numa resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Matheus**, você pode usar `Bootstrap`:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#meuLoginModal" >Login</a>

        <div class="modal hide" id="meuLoginModal">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
            <h3>Meu Login</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" action='' name="login_form">
              <p><input type="text" class="span3" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
              <p><input type="password" class="span3" name="passwd" placeholder="Senha"></p>
              <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
                <a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            Novo aqui?
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/ox8rsmdz/5/)**

Comment: valeu cara muito obrigado pela ajuda